# How to get counts of grouped related items in prisma?

Tags: prisma

I have a table of Posts and a table of Reactions. A reaction is a tuple of `[userId, postId, reactionType]` where reactionType is an enum of "like", "thumbsup" and so on. So when a user "likes" a post, it adds a "like" reaction to the reaction table.

What I want is to query a list of posts, and for each post I want to get the count of reactions of each type. So for post A I would have 3 likes and 1 thumbsup, for post B I would have 0 likes and 2 thumbsup and so on. I don't want to get the actual reactions themselves because there could be potentially thousands of reactions for each post, I just want to get the count.

Is there a way to express this in Prisma, or do I need to dive down to raw SQL? I'm using PostgreSQL as the underlying db.

Comment: You utilize Prisma's [groupBy and count feature](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/aggregation-grouping-summarizing) as documented in the link.

Comment: What I didn't realize is that groupBy has to be done as a separate query, it can't be done as a subquery in prisma. In raw SQL, I could get both the posts and the reaction counts in a single query, but in prisma you have to do one query for the posts and a second query for the reaction counts and associate them afterwards.

Comment: You would need to resort to Raw Query for this, you can get count of one reaction type, but not the count of all reaction types. You can only have one _count field in single query.